# Show that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite but is $\Sigma$-finite (Çınlar Exercise 3.13 d)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is Exercise 3.13 d) from *Probability and Stochastics*, by Erhan Çınlar.

**Request:**

I would appreciate help finishing this exercise. I think I've successfully shown that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, but I'm not sure how to show that it is $\Sigma$-finite, and I'm pretty sure my attempt below is wrong.

**Definitions:**

A measure $\mu$ on $(E, \mathscr{E})$ is said to be $\Sigma$-finite if there exists a sequence of finite measures $(\mu_n)$ such that $\mu = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu_n$.

The Dirac measure at $x$ is written $\delta_x$.

**Problem:**

> Let $E = [0, 1]$ and $\mathscr{E} = \mathscr{B}(E)$. For $A$ in $E$, define $\mu(A)$ to be $0$ if $\text{Leb } A = 0$ and $+\infty$ if $\text{Leb } A > 0$. Show that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite but is $\Sigma$-finite.

**My attempt:**

To show that $\sigma$-finiteness is false, we can proceed by contradiction. If there were a measurable partition $(E_n)$ of $E$ such that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for each $n$, then by the definition of $\mu$, we'd have $\mu(E_n) = 0$ for each $n$, which implies that $\text{Leb } (E_n) = 0$ for each $n$. This implies that
\begin{align*}
    1 &= \text{Leb } [0, 1]\\
    &= \text{Leb } \left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_n\right)\\
    &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \text{Leb } (E_n)\\
    &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 0\\
    &= 0,
\end{align*}
which is clearly a contradiction.

Next, we want to prove that $\mu$ is $\Sigma$-finite. Consider the measure defined by
\begin{align*}
    \mu'(A) &:= \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]} \delta_q(A)
\end{align*}
for $A \in \mathscr{B}(E)$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, this is a countable sum, and each $\delta_q$ is finite, as it is a Dirac measure.

**Comment:**

Clearly I'm not going to be able to show that $\mu = \mu'$, because $\mu \bigl( \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1] \bigr) = 0$ whereas $\mu' \bigl( \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1] \bigr) = \infty$. I feel like I need to use Dirac measures here, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It would be nice if you give the definition of $\Sigma-$ finite. It is not found in standard measure theory books.

Comment: what about $\mu_n=\textrm{Leb}$

Comment: @Snoop That's interesting! I think it might work. I'll think about it a bit.